# Duplicated response from Google Console application

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created a Google assistant application which is connected to Dialog Flow project.

[image: Acton]

And the I have deployed it as Alpha release and tried to test it with mobile phone.
The issue I'm facing is all the responses from the application is duplicated, but when I
test it from the Action Console simulator or from Dialog flow it works fine.

[image: Issue]

Tried deleting and recreating the google project but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In your intent on dialogueflow can you check under `Responses` if the Google Assistant action is un-toggled?:

```
Use responses from the DEFAULT tab as the first responses
```

[image]

Alternatively you can try deleting your default responses and set only the Google Assistant action. Possibly the intent's `Default` and `Google Assistant` response are sending both responses to dialogflow causing  duplicate response.

Comment: Only the Default Responses are enabled in my Dialog Flow project.

Comment: Can you try enabling the Google Assistant actions ( clicking the "+" icon) instead and delete the default responses  as mentioned above answer?

Comment: Enabled the Google Assistant actions and then disabled the option, still getting duplicated responses